# Writing code with ";" instead of newlines

Tags: bash

The following code throws compilation error with message "syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'" or "unexpected end of file".

```
#!/bin/bash
pas=total ; echo "Put your paswword here: " ; if read -t 4 passw then ; if [ $passw=$pas ] then ; echo "Right password"  else ; echo "Wrong password"  fi  else ; echo "Wrong password" ; fi ;
```

Please explain, where is the mistake? Or teach me how to write Bash code with `;`, without moving on to a new line.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52059765/edit) to include more information.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is your friend ;)

Comment: The simplest way to generate correct ; split commands is to type them in with newlines, then look in the history buffer for the semicolon version.

Comment: Note that writing your whole script on a single line is a bad practice that impeds readability. It's fine if it's your own script (altough you might curse yourself in a few months), but you should avoid this if you're working in a team.

Comment: Check out the [syntax for the `if` command in the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-if) and observe where there are semicolons – those shouldn't be removed when reformatting to a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try this:

```
pas=total ; echo "Put your paswword here: " ; if read -t 4 passw ; then if [ $passw=$pas ]; then  echo "Right password";  else  echo "Wrong password"; fi else  echo "Wrong password" ; fi ;
```

In an if statement you have to include the semicolon after the condition and after the code that is to be executed:

```
if [ ... ]; then ... ; fi
```

Additionally you don't need a semicolon after an else.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what you changed, i.e., pointing out that there is a `;` required after the condition in an "if" statement.